# XMLHTTPRequest fails on large files

Tags: xmlhttprequest

XMLHTTPRequest fails when I send a large file (>700MB) over .send().  Even worse, BlobBuilder fails for large files with append() as well.  Is there a way to send a file in multiple chunks using XMLHTTPRequest? How do I tell the server to "append" the following stream of data?

Comment: How are you getting the data?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I'm using Chrome and I'm not even getting any exceptions thrown, it just chokes and I get a "something went wrong" error page (the built-in chrome one)

Comment: I remember it was said that files are directly streamed from the disk. And sometimes they are. But sometimes they are not and I'm now facing this problem. It's definitely not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of the server as well as the client, I'd suggest the following workaround:

1. break the file up into chunks (`.slice()`)
2. upload the multiple file chunks
3. reassemble the file chunks on the server

I don't know that this problem can be solved strictly within the browser.

Comment: Can you tell more how to slice file? It is possible with FileData or just Blob?